# Determining suitable time lag in Granger causality test

Tags: regression, granger-causality

In order to determine the right time lag for the Granger causality test, I applied a cross correlation function (CCF) among EU and National legislation and the CCF figure is attached.
I would be grateful if you could kindly help me in resolving the following concerns:

- I am wondering what time-lag you recommend based on the attached figure?
- To find the greatest value in CCF figure, should I consider absolute values or just the raw values?
- If we consider the negative values in CCF Figure, then I assume the result of Granger causality test would show the negative causality, correct?
- I am interested in one side of the causality (Effect of EU on National and Not the vice versa), so, should I only consider the bound [-5...0]?

Comment: You need more reputation to post images, but you are able to post data and/or printed output from the software you used, such as numeric tabulation of CCF.

Comment: The OP says the figure is attached but there is no figure here. It seems to be lost during the editing.

Answer (score 1):

Does the lag identification procedure have to be applied using the cross correlation? If not, I would recommend the function `VARselect()` from the package [vars](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/index.html) in the R programming environment. This function suggests different optimal lags according to some information criteria (AIC, HQ, SC and FPE). Once you have chosen the lag, you can perform a Granger causality test using another function from the same package `causality()`.

Comment: What language is this and how do you know the OP is using it?

Comment: The language is, of cource, R.

Comment: As neither R nor any other language is a declared default on this site, it is a matter of courtesy as well as information always to explain the language being used. The second half of my question remains....

Comment: I can only suggest a language I use...

Comment: Naturally I agree with that. However, the question is not about software, but about methods, so in principle a fair answer need not mention software at all. In practice we can't see the OP's graphs, but that's a different point.